# MS Access: Show string in the date field when empty

Tags: date, ms-access, input-mask, propertysheet

I'm looking to have my field show "dd-mmm-yy" when a date is not entered into the field, so members don't get confused and frustrated when they try to put in a date such as 11/12/20 and don't realize it needs to be in day day, month month month, year year format. Is this possible to do through the property sheet?

[date format]

Comment: Doubt that can be done with textbox bound to date/time field. Have a label with big red message "Enter as dd-mmm-yyyy".

Comment: I also have input mask on, but I was wondering if it's possible to show the string "dd-mmm-yy" when the field is blank to show members what format to type it in.

Comment: You read my first comment before I edited it. Might review again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the *Format* property of the textbox to:

```
dd-mm-yyyy;;;"dd-mm-yyyy"
```

though I believe it will add more confusion than help.

Another method for speedy input of dates is shown in my article:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!